# Why do the Textillate effects remove the bold formatting?

Tags: jquery, html, letteringjs

Why do the Textillate effects remove the bold formatting from `h3` tags in my portfolio and how do you fix it? https://codepen.io/Olliewe88/pen/pgmWor

```js
$(function() {
  $('h1').textillate();
  $('h2').textillate({ in: {
      effect: 'flip'
    }
  });
  $('h3').textillate({ in: {
      effect: 'rollIn'
    }
  });
  $('h4').textillate({ in: {
      effect: 'tada'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #00ffff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed;
}

h4 {
  font-family: Open Sans Condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #8f8f8f;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.7.0/jquery.lettering.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textillate/0.4.0/jquery.textillate.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <h1 class="text-primary text-center">Martin Luther King
    <h1>
      <h2 class="text-center">"Life's most persistent and urgent question is, 'What are you doing for others?"</h2>
      <div class="jumbotron">

        <center>
          <img class="img-responsive  ialign=" middle " src="http://static6.businessinsider.com/image/54bc1ccbecad04fb41e364cc/the-most-iconic-parts-from-martin-luther-kings-i-have-a-dream-speech.jpg ">
    </center>
  
<h3 class='tests'><ul>
   <li><b>January 15 1929</b> Martin Luther King, Jr. is born in Atlanta, Georgia. </li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>June 1948</b> King graduates from Morehouse College in Atlanta </li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>September 1948 </b> King enrolls in Crozer Theological Seminary in Chester, Pennsylvania</li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>June 18 1953 </b> King marries Coretta Scott in Marion, Alabama</li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>December 1955 </b> King is elected the president of the Montgomery Improvement Association.</li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>January 30 1956 </b> King's house is bombed</li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>January 1957 </b> King is elected president of the Southern Christian Leadership Conference</li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>September 1958 </b> King's first book, "Stride Toward Freedom " is published.</li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>October 19, 1960 </b> King is arrested in Atlanta</li> </ul></h3>
<h3><ul>
   <li><b>April 1963 </b> King is arrested in Birmingham, Alabama</li> </ul></h3>
  
 <h2 class="text-center ">"Faith is taking the first step even when you don 't see the whole staircase"</h2> 
  
  <center><h4>I recommend you should <a target="_blank" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King,_Jr.">click here to read more!</a></h4><center>
    <p>Page coded by Oliver Webb, for a project at <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com" target="_blank">FreeCodeCamp</a></p> 
  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add font-weight in the css file

```
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### text in `<h3>` are set to bold by default, see the example yourself.

What you can do is not using h3, define the text font yourself, then use

> [image]
>
> REF: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

```css
.tests2 {
  font-size: 1.17em;
}

.tests3 {
  font-size: 1.17em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h3 class='tests'>
  <ul>
    <li><b>January 15 1929</b> Martin Luther King, Jr. is born in Atlanta, Georgia. </li>
  </ul>
</h3>


<div class='tests2'>
  <ul>
    <li><b>January 15 1929</b> Martin Luther King, Jr. is born in Atlanta, Georgia. </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class='tests3'>
  <ul>
    <li><b>January 15 1929</b> Martin Luther King, Jr. is born in Atlanta, Georgia. </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```